# How to split a text with variable length delimeter

Tags: python, regex

Ive got this text

```
        Flu and pneumonia affect millions of people each year in the <em>United States</em>. .... 
Adams Pharmacy and Home Care. . . . . . . . .1961 First Ave,
         Opelika, AL 36801 . ...... Frys Food and Drug . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .8900 E
         Via <em>Linda</em>, Scottsdale, AZ 85258 . ...... American Health Solutions 
        Pharmacy Inc . . . . .3463 <em>Overland Ave</em>, Los ...
```

I want to split it into these 7 elements **[ REQUIRED OUTPUT]** :-

```
 - Flu and pneumonia affect millions of people each year in the <em>United States</em>
 - Adams Pharmacy and Home Care
 - 1961 First Ave, Opelika, AL 36801
 - Frys Food and Drug 
 - 8900 E Via <em>Linda</em>, Scottsdale, AZ 85258
 - American Health Solutions Pharmacy Inc
 - 3463 <em>Overland Ave</em>, Los
```

I tried

```
new_st.split(". .")
```

and

```
new_st.split(".")
```

But none of them are able to give me the output I need.

Comment: Try splitting on the following regex: https://regex101.com/r/7KMe5I/1

Comment: Split with `r'\s*(?:\.\s*){2,}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to perform the splitting and then clean up the output a little:

```
strs = re.split(r'\s*\.+\s*', s)
strs = [i.strip() for i in strs if i]
```

The second line gets rid of the empty strings as a result of the split and then `strip()` gets rid of extraneous whitespaces

If you wish to split on `n` or more dots (without spaces), you can use the following regex:

```
\s*\.{3,}\s*
```

And with spaces:

```
(\s*\.\s*){3,}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to split on more than two full stops ? For instance, this (st) should get split into three  phrases :: st="Jul 14, 2017 - 3650 Overland Avenue ... State. County. Zip Code. Contact. Rodney Lind. Telephone ... This is a copy view of the Authorative Copy held."   ===OUTPUT===> 1.] Jul 14, 2017 - 3650 Overland Avenue          2.] State. County. Zip Code. Contact. Rodney Lind. Telephone                3.]This is a copy view of the Authorative Copy held

Comment: thanks shashank but its not working on previous input. Is there a single regex/way which can deal with both the inputs and provide output as required/stated

Comment: Well your previous input has spread out dots (with spaces in between), so it has to be one or the other unless you still would want the spread out dots to be at least 3 or more?